# Cycle space and chordal graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I was working with chordal graphs and the connection to the cycle space, i.e. the $\mathbb{F}_2$-vectorspace on the set of all edges with the fundamental cycles as a basis.

I initially thought that any cycle that is generated by triangles in the cycle space is chordal. However, this is certainly not true. Take a wheel (a vertex with a (chordless) cycle in its neighbourhood).

Now I was wondering if that is the only obstruction in the sense that if we forbid such wheels as induced subgraphs then every cycle that is generated by triangles is chordal.

I'd appreciate any kind of insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting question! Here's my crack at it (also, an unstated assumption is that there's at most one edge between two vertices):

Let $G$ be a graph for which this statement is false, and let $C = T_1 + T_2 + \ldots + T_n$ be the cycle in question. Well, assuming $C$ is not just a triange, to fulfill the chordless requirement, there has to be at least one vertex $x$ that is a part of some $T_i$, but not of $C$. Now, let $I$ be the set of all $i$ for which $x$ is a vertex in $T_i$.

Take some $T_i$ with $i \in I$, and let $E$ be an edge of it connected to $x$. Since $E$ is not an edge in $C$, there has to be at least one $j \in I$ such that $i \neq j$ and $E$ is an edge of $T_j$. Well, if we repeat this process with the other edge connected to $x$ of $T_j$, we'll get some triangle $T_k$ and so on. Eventually we will have to loop around at some point, which creates a wheel with center $x$.

Edit: I just realized this proof needs a small amendment. I have successfully proven (I think) that our graph $G$ must contain a wheel as a subgraph, but not as an induced subgraph. Luckily, this is only a slight hinderance: if you add an extra edge to a wheel somewhere, it's easy to see that you can remove some verticies to get a smaller wheel.

Comment: Why do we have to loop around? I don't think this is right, see my answer below.

Comment: @MathieuRundström because there are only finitely many options to choose from.

Comment: That should work. Thank you!
Also funny that it doesn't matter if we talk about wheels as subgraphs or induced subgraphs.

Comment: What if the wheel you construct is a $W_5$ with a chord? You cannot get a smaller wheel since any smaller wheel will be chordal.

Comment: @caduk no, you can get the $W_4$ wheel, which is a complete graph so kind of definitionally can't have a chord.

Comment: How do me make sure that we actually get an induced $W_5$ by the above procedure and not just $W_4$s? 
So far we are not guaranteed to find one, right?
But ideally we do, because if we look at the $W_4$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$ that would give us a triangle which is technically chordal.

Comment: Ok, it depends on the interpretation of the question. $W_k$ with $k\geq 5$ is an obstruction because if we find such an induced $W_k$, we already know that the graph is not chordal. However, if we find an induced $W_4$, the graph can still be chordal, so I didn't counted it as an obstruction. (For me, the word obstruction are unavoidable patterns that guarantee the property, otherwise, I would have just called that an unavoidable induced subgraph). @Jonas, can you enlighten us on if $W_4$ are allowed as obstructions ?

Comment: @caduk yeah I just realised, see the comment above. I don't want an induced $W_4$, I want any induced $W_k$ for $k\geq 5$.

Comment: @Jonas wait, why not $k \geq 4$?

Comment: However, thinking of it, the only meaningful obstruction for $W_4$ is $W_4$, Maybe the interesting question is if a graph has a chordless cycle of size $\geq4$ (and a triangle cycle basis), then what are the obstructions?