# Self-contained classes of graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

Yesterday, I was answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4854568/cycle-space-and-chordal-graphs/4854624#4854624), where as a part of the proof, I had to use the fact that any graph that contains a wheel as a subgraph also must contain a wheel as an induced subgraph (note that we assume a graph can have at most one edge between a pair of verticies, the statement is false otherwise).

This made me think that that's a curious proberty for a class of graphs to have, and I tried to think of other classes with this property. I came up with the class of cycles, the class of complete graphs, and any class of graphs that contains the single-point graph pretty quickly.

So, here's my first (and harder) question: let a class $\mathcal{C}$ of graphs be called $\textbf{self-contained}$ if for all graphs $G$, if $G$ contains an element of $\mathcal{C}$ as a subgraph, it also contains an element (not nessesarily the same one) as an induced subgraph (we will also assume all graphs to be finite and connected). Can we categorize all such classes?

Some of the categorization can be done pretty easily: all such classes have to contain a minimal (in the sense that no other graph in the class has less verticies) complete graph. That graph we will call the $\textbf{base}$ of the class.

We can also see that the union of two self-contained classes is again a self-contained class. Also, if we take two self contained classes $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ and create a new class $\mathcal{E}$ that contains all graphs we can attain by taking the disjoint union of $G_1 \in \mathcal{C}$ and $G_2 \in \mathcal{D}$, and then creating an edge between any $a,b$ with $a \in G_1$ and $b \in G_2$; then the class $\mathcal{E}$ will be self contained. Thus, a complete classification effort would likely need to come up with a condition that makes a self-contained class "primitive" with respect to these operations.

The second question is intended as a simplification of this problem to get some sort of a foothold. Let's call a self-contained class $\mathcal{C}$ $\textbf{simple}$ if, given it has as base the complete graph of order $n$, it holds that for all natural numbers $m \geq n$ there is exactly one graph of order $m$ in $\mathcal{C}$, and removing finitely many graphs from $\mathcal{C}$ does not result in a self-contained class. Can we classify simple self contained classes? I would be even satisfied if it was done just for classes with small bases.

As examples, one can show that the class of cycles and the class of wheels are both simple (with bases of size 3 and 4 respectively).

This is about as far as I got on my own, any ideas would be aprechiated.

Comment: The operation you describe with graph $G_1$ and $G_2$ is called the *graph join* and commonly denoted $G_1 + G_2$. The wheel graphs are graphs of the form $C_n + K_1$, so they are not "primitive" in this respect; we obtain them from the self-contained class $\{C_n : n\ge 3\}$ of all cycles, and the finite and trivially self-contained class $\{K_1\}$. Similarly, the set of all graphs of the form $C_n + K_m$ (for a fixed $m$) is self-contained and simple - but not primitive, so it's not very interesting.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I didn't even consider that, but you're right, wheels would not be primitive in this sense.